# How to make appointment only if day name corresponding with available day of other table called doctor_timings,php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

im really new and the first time trying to use stackoverflow for answer purpose (sorry).

I have two tables one table is the `doctor_timings` table where i have an available day and i have the table `patient` and have the table `appointment`,i need to book an appointment only when the extracted day from imput type date finished on php file acord or equals to available day of doctor_timings table,but i need to insert  with this condition on appointment table if condition are true im tried

```
sql = "INSERT INTO appointment WHERE '$appointment_day' = available_day "; 
$Result = $Conexion -> query($sql);
```

where available day in query are the data from tavle `doctor_timings` (available day),prevouslo store available day making an `SELECT query` from table `doctor_timings` with available day data.. but really im not sure to compose teh query correctly

please i need our help to compose correctly query to make an appointment while name of the day entered on input type date and extrated after equals to available day data of `doctor_timings` table and make the appointment in this way in to table `appointment`, thanks for our help.

**this is my php code (spanish):**

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){
    
    require 'conexion.php';
    
    $nombre = $_POST['name'];
    
    $fecha_cita = $_POST['fecha_cita'];
    
    $dia_cita = date("D", strtotime($fecha_cita));
    
    $hora_cita = $_POST['hora'];
    
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    
    $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
    
    $correo = $_POST['email'];
    
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];
    
    $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
    
    $doctor = $_POST['doctor'];
    
    $tratamiento = $_POST['tratamiento'];
    
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    
    $sql_verificar_existencia_usuario = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE loginid='$correo'";

    $Result_verificar_existencia_usuario = $Conexion -> query($sql_verificar_existencia_usuario)or die($Conexion -> error);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($Result_verificar_existencia_usuario) >= 1){
        
        //header('location: index.php?error=1');
        
    }else{
        
        include 'conexion.php';
        
        $sql_registro_paciente = "INSERT INTO patient(
                                    patientname,
                                    admissiondate,
                                    admissiontime,
                                    historia_num,
                                    historia,
                                    prescripcion_medica,
                                    tratamiento,
                                    mobileno,
                                    city,
                                    pincode,
                                    loginid,
                                    password,
                                    bloodgroup,
                                    dob,
                                    status,
                                    delete_status)
                                    VALUES(
                                    '$nombre',
                                    '$fecha_cita',
                                    '$hora_cita',
                                    '',
                                    '',
                                    '',
                                    '',
                                    '$telefono',
                                    '$ciudad',
                                    '',
                                    '$correo',
                                    '$clave',
                                    '',
                                    '$fecha_nacimiento',
                                    'Active',
                                    '0'
                                    )";

        $Result_registro_paciente = $Conexion -> query($sql_registro_paciente)or die($Conexion -> error);

        if($Result_registro_paciente == true){

            include 'conexion.php';

            $sql_traer_paciente_registrado = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE loginid='$correo'";

            $Result_paciente_registrado = $Conexion -> query($sql_traer_paciente_registrado)or die($Conexion -> error);

            while($PacienteRegistrado = $Result_paciente_registrado -> fetch_assoc()){

                $id_paciente = $PacienteRegistrado['patientid'];

            }

            if($Result_paciente_registrado == true){
                
                //Traemos los dias libres del odontologo
                $sql_traer_dias_libres_odontologo = "SELECT available_day FROM doctor_timings WHERE doctorid='2'";
                
                $Result_traer_dias_libres_odontologo = $Conexion -> query($sql_traer_dias_libres_odontologo)or die($Conexion -> error);
                
                while($DiasLibresOdontologo = $Result_traer_dias_libres_odontologo -> fetch_assoc()){
                    
                     $DiasLibres = $DiasLibresOdontologo[4];
                    
                }
                //Evaluamos el dia de la cita si coincide con los dias libres del odontologo

                $sql_crear_cita_paciente = "INSERT INTO appointment(
                                                appointmenttype,
                                                patientid,
                                                roomid,
                                                departmentid,
                                                appointmentdate,
                                                appointmenttime,
                                                doctorid,
                                                status,
                                                app_reason,
                                                detalles_sintomas,
                                                delete_status
                                                )VALUES(
                                                'odontologia',
                                                '$id_paciente',
                                                '0',
                                                '1',
                                                '$fecha_cita',
                                                '$hora_cita',
                                                '2',
                                                'Active',
                                                '$tratamiento',
                                                '$mensaje',
                                                '0'
                                                )";

                $Result_crear_cita_paciente = $Conexion -> query($sql_crear_cita_paciente)or die($Conexion -> error);
                
                //header('location: index.php?exito=1');

            }

        }else{

        }
        
    }
    
}
?>
```

this is the doctor_timings table (image):
[image]

Comment: Hi! Kindly provide the `CREATE Statement` for your table and provide some sample data using `INSERT INTO statement` for us to easily simulate the output. Thank you

Comment: And your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injections**, try using [**PHP MySQL Prepared Statements**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Hi im not sure about retrieving data from INSERT INTO,because i have this condition on my query..                                                                                   "INSERT INTO appointment WHERE '$php_day_name_variable'='available_day'"; but available_day is a row of other table called "doctor_timings" and php variable is data fetched from the form input type date and extracted day,when tried to run this query can see message "you have an error in your sql sintaxis,please see the documentation corresponding with your maria DB ..."

Comment: Uhm I'm just asking for the table schema so that other users like me can simulate the problem.